# Can't disable active window's transparency | Hover effect not working

Tags: 11.10, window-manager, window-buttons, transparency

I'm having a problem right now with my window frames' opacity settings. 
For some reason the active window very often (but not always) has a half-transparent title bar. This is really distracting but so far I haven't found any way of getting rid of this effect.

[image]

I think the problem might be caused by settings I made using the "Ubuntu Tweak" tool. But whenever I try to reset the window frame settings in "Ubuntu Tweak" the application crashes. I already tried reinstalling it but the problem still remains.

Additionally the hover effects (on the max, min, and close button) are not working properly.

Do you know how to reset the  window frames' opacity settings so that active window frames have no transparency at all?

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands in the terminal to fix the title bar opacity:

```
gconftool-2  -s --type=bool /apps/gwd/metacity_theme_shade_opacity 0
gconftool-2  -s --type=bool /apps/gwd/metacity_theme_active_shade_opacity 0
```

I'm not sure about the hover effects.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Veazer! This indeed helps as it stops the active window from being half-transparent. Still the active window's frame remains "colorless" (the close button is not orange) and the hover effects don't work. Only when I maximize the window and then restore it afterwards the close button will turn orange (with the hover effects still not working).
It seems as if ubuntu does not realize when a windows focus is changed and treats the active window as if it was inactive.
Anyway, thank you very much so far. As soon as I am able to upvote for you post I will do so.